# React JSON Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'questionText')

Tags: reactjs

it works properly when I use the JSON data in the commented area. However, When I try to use the axios it gives errors. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'questionText'). Where am I making a mistake? I could not find it. I tried by using class and state but is still gives same error. I check the JSON coming from PHP api, it is totally same as in the commented area.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import './Quiz.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import PopupLogout from './PopupLogout.js';
import {faXmark} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

function Quiz(){



    // const questions = [
    //  {
    //      questionText: 'What is the capital of France?',
    //      answerOptions: [
    //          { answerText: 'New York', isCorrect: false },
    //          { answerText: 'London', isCorrect: false },
    //          { answerText: 'Paris', isCorrect: true },
    //      ],
    //  },
    //  {
    //      questionText: 'Who is CEO of Tesla?',
    //      answerOptions: [
    //          { answerText: 'Jeff Bezos', isCorrect: false },
    //          { answerText: 'Elon Musk', isCorrect: true },
    //          { answerText: 'Bill Gates', isCorrect: false },
    //      ],
    //  },
    //  {
    //      questionText: 'The iPhone was created by which company?',
    //      answerOptions: [
    //          { answerText: 'Apple', isCorrect: true },
    //          { answerText: 'Intel', isCorrect: false },
    //          { answerText: 'Microsoft', isCorrect: false },
    //      ],
    //  },
    //  {
    //      questionText: 'How many Harry Potter books are there?',
    //      answerOptions: [
    //          { answerText: '1', isCorrect: false },
    //          { answerText: '7', isCorrect: false },
    //          { answerText: '8', isCorrect: true },
    //      ],
    //  },
    // ];

    var questions = [];
    const getData = () =>{
     axios.get('http://localhost/getQuestions.php',{withCredentials: true})
     .then(res => {
      //console.log(res.data);
      questions = res.data;
      //console.log(questions2);

      //console.log(questions);
     })
   
     } 
     getData();
    
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const[currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    const[popup, setPopup] = useState(false);
 

    const handleButtonClick =(isCorrect) =>{
        const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        if(nextQuestion <questions.length )
        {
            setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
        }
        else{
           setPopup(true);
            setTimeout(function() {
                navigate("../dashboard");
                window.location.reload(true)
              }, 3000);
              
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <nav className="quiz-nav" >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faXmark} id="out-logo" />

            </nav>
            <div className="main-quiz">
                <div className="progressbar" ></div>
                <div className="question">{questions[currentQuestion].questionText}</div>
                <div className="answers">

                    {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOptions) =>(
                        <button onClick={handleButtonClick} ><div className="choice">{answerOptions.answerText}</div></button>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
            <PopupLogout trigger={popup} > You finished it! You will be redirected to the dashboard. </PopupLogout>
        </div>
    );}export default Quiz;
```

Comment: Do some additional sanity tests to make sure the json is actually the same. Stringify both objects and see if they're equal.

Comment: I think I found the problem the first data coming from axios is empty. {questions: Array(0)}, {questions: Array(0)}, {questions: Array(4)} comes like this. But it is in UseEffect why this is happening?